# Развернуть backup на резервном сервере Oracle

Tags: oracle, rman

Как развернуть backup, сделанный с помощью RMAN на резервном сервере?
Так же интересует, не важно ли для переноса, какая ОС системы?
На работающем сервере БД был запущен Rman и выполненны следующие команды:

```
connect target;
shutdown immediate;
startup mount;
backup database;
alter database open;
```

Затем файлы бекапа были скопированны на ПК где планируется развернуть резервную БД путь к папке E:\backup. На резервном ПК был запущен Rman со следующими командами:

```
connect target;
shutdown immediate;
startup mount;
catalog start with 'E:\backup\';
```

Затем соглашаюсь добавить данные бекапы написав yes. Затем получаю ошибку

> File Name:  путь и имя файла
>
> RMAN-07518: Reson: Foreign
>
> database file DBID: 4099333308
>
> Database Name: ORCL

Затем где-то читал, что можно написать `set DBID 4099333308` и повторить заново, но ничего не вышло. БД даже не поднялась, указывая на то, что неверный DBID. Поэтому DBID я вернул какой был. Как решить проблему?

Comment: Вы можете посмотреть, куда можно перенести:  `select * from v$db_transportable_platform`. Какова цель? Обычно исплользуют для переноса dump.

Comment: @0xdb мне нужно сделать резервную БД на другом сервере. Вот главная моя цель. Как сделать это правильно не знаю. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: "резервную БД" - что вы под этим понимаете? Standby?

Comment: @0xdb мне нужно просто перенести данные, триггеры, сиквенсы, вьюшки с одной базы в другую новую. Создав грубо говоря зеркало первой. Потом раз в неделю например вручную дополнять недостающей информацией. Тоесть сервер как бы стоит в холодном резерве. И в нужный момент может быть использован в качестве основного

Comment: Тогда, правильно, RMAN. Попробуйте [так](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58435/oracle-restore-backup-on-other-server).

Comment: @0xdb не получается, пишет ошибку RMAN-07518: Reason: Foreign database file DBID:4099333308 Database Name: ORCL. Пробовал set DBID не помогает. Это значит что не получится восстановить базу если вдруг с ней что-то случится???

Comment: Добавте в вопрос, что вы сделали, что использовали и сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: А ORCL это у вас так действительно продуктивная база называется?

Comment: @0xdb нет конечно это я для примера. Но имя базы что на основной что на резервной одинаковое сделал.

Comment: Хорошо, подождём, может DBA откликнутся. И ешё, вы упоминали, что перенос на другую ОС. Имеет ли смысл делать резервную машину с другой ОС?

Comment: @0xdb к сожалению имеет смысл. Сейчас все крутится под CentOS 7. Резерв под win server 2012

Comment: А почему вы не зададите этот вопрос на [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com)? Здесь не совсем по теме потому, что связан с администрированием БД, а там точно в тему.

Comment: @0xdb `Какие вопросы можно задавать?` `Здесь можно задать любой вопрос, относящийся:` `к проектированию, использованию и администрированию баз данных;` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic А на dba.stackexchange язык заморский (;

Comment: @4per я не утжерждал, что оффтоп, конечно можно. Но тема не в главном фокусе. У вас, несмотря на конкурс, пока один ответ, там было бы несколько по более того. Ну и что, что заморский? Вы же уже задавали вопросы на заморском (да, и поменяйте там ник, а то неблагозвучен) .

Comment: @4per PS сорри, с ТС перепутал

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Возможно проблема из за того что вы не восстановили SPFILE и CONTROLFILE.

1. Стартуем БД без монтирования spfile:

startup nomount;

2. Восстанавливаем spfile:

restore spfile from ’путь к файлу в бекапе *.CTF’;

3. Останавливаем

shutdown immediate;

4. Стартуем в режиме nomount,и восстанавливаем контрольный файл:

restore controlfile from  ’путь к файлу в бекапе *.CTF’;

5. Стартуем в режиме mount

startup mount.

6. catalog start with ‘полный путь к папке бекапа’;
7. Соглашаемся: Y
8. run
   {
   restore database;
   recover database;
   }
9. После восстановления появится ошибка, SCN не сходится. Сбрасываем SCN и стартуем

alter database open resetlogs;

Если исходный сервер(Oracle) был 32-битный а новый 64 то необходимо выполнить в sqlplus:

```
startup upgrade
@$Oracle_Home\rdbms\admin\utlip.sql
@$Oracle_Home\rdbms\admin\catupgrd.sql
@$Oracle_Home\rdbms\admin\utlrp.sql
shutdown immediate
startup
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Буду пробовать уже на другом ПК. Копии перенес кустарным способом через expdp и impdp